# how to make to type only 80 in search box

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to make a search box where users can only type up to its 80%  by default coming cross icon here just little bit its right I want to add a search icon how to do this.
This is my searchbox [move cross icon little bit left to add another search icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE4Kp.png)

I want to make
[search box like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcnyn.png)

```
#searchBtn {
                margin-left: 0px;
                color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                background-color: rgba(252, 174, 158, 0);
                border: none;
            }
            #searchBox {
                margin-left: 0px;
    
            } 
    
    <div class="searchbox">
            <input type="search" name="" id="searchBox">
            <button id="searchBtn" type="submit"><i class="far fa-search"></i></button>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the border to the container instead of the input.

```css
.searchbox {
    width: fit-content;
    width: -moz-fit-content;

    border: solid 1px black;
}

#searchBox {
    border: none;
}
```